# jboss-5.1.0.GA startup issue

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I am trying to configure jboss-5.1.0.GA server for my application on linux platform. When I am starting the server I can see in the log that it starts successfully, but when I am trying to access the started port(8080 by default) it shows no response from server as if server not started. Can any one please help me to sort out this thing.

Comment: Off topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: Also, how do you expect anybody to help you with NO information at all beyond "it doesn't work"?  Imagine calling your doctor on the phone and saying "I have a problem".  What would his response be?

Comment: could you please specify whether you're running a jboss on remote machine, or you're running the linux and using the browser to connect from the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

these are just reasonable guesses, but try the following:

start your server on a commandline with following option:

```
-b 0.0.0.0
```

try following options to check if your server is running:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/

http://localhost:8080/

http://(your ip):8080/
```

good luck